Understand the knot group of unlink
I have the difficulty to understand the knot group of the 2-component link in $\mathbb{R}^3$, especially it is not commutitive. Let $l=l_1\cup l_2$ be the union of two unrelated unknots. The knot group $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3-l)$ is a free group of two generators. I draw a picture as the following.
I can see that $ab\neq ba$. But it seems to me that $a^{-1}b=ba^{-1}$. They are both looks to me like the picture in below. 
As the knot group is a free group, it is impossible. I cannot understand where is wrong.

You could have said the same thing for $ab$ vs $ba$. The point is that these two are not homotopic. Same is true for $a^{-1}b$ vs $ ba^{-1}$. Try to construct a homotopy between them and see why it doesn’t exist.

Now I see. There is no way to construct a homotopy if I keep one base point fixed.

Remember that the order of traversal matters, as does the basepoint. In your second diagram, you don't specify a basepoint, which might be the source of your confusion.
Yes, the loop in your second diagram could represent $a^{-1}b$ and $ba^{-1}$. But there are two points where orange and blue meet. $a^{-1}b$ has the lower point as its basepoint, and $ba^{-1}$ as its upper.
I could equally well draw a "proof" of $ab=ba$:
 where again the basepoint is the difference.
I hope this helps.

Thanks for drawing the graph. I thought those two points of the loop can be continously deformed into one point. So it is no problem to separate them. This maybe where I got confused.
